# Avoid writing in output file using Transformer in XML

Tags: java, xml

I want to store my transformed XML in memory.

Here is my code snippet

```
public static void xmlProcessor(String stylesheetPathname, String inputPathname, String outputPathname ) throws TransformerException {

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source stylesheetSource = new StreamSource(new File(stylesheetPathname).getAbsoluteFile());
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(stylesheetSource);
        Source inputSource = new StreamSource(new File(inputPathname).getAbsoluteFile());
        Result outputResult = new StreamResult(new File(outputPathname).getAbsoluteFile());
        transformer.transform(inputSource, outputResult);

    }
```

`transformer.transform(inputSource, outputResult)`; this call is writing the output XML in file. I want to know , Is there any way I could store this transformed XML in any object and use it later in my code.

Object storage (That's Where I'm thinking to store my transformed XML)

```
protected static Map<String, Object> transformedXMLMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I want to do it, so that I could avoid IO operation on transformed XML. And once utilized, I'll empty the map.

Any suggestions please..!

Comment: `Result outputResult` is the object, you can refer later.

Comment: @Deb, Nope its not. I need the transformed XML in object in memory but not on disc

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the serialized XML result in a string variable:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Result outputResult = new StreamResult(sw);
transformer.transform(inputSource, outputResult);
String lexicalXmlResult = sw.toString();
```

and of course you can store the `String` in a map, but I'm not sure why you want to.

Comment: I'm doing it so that I dont need to write transformed XML to disc, becasue I'm going to use transformed XML to convert into JSON later.

Comment: Yes, but why a map? Once you've got it in a string, you can do anything you like with it.

Comment: That makes sense, but now am getting error at Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(stylesheetSource);, saying that "Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet"  Any Idea , why its that ..?

Comment: No idea, seems a quite unrelated problem.